Not able to install tokenizers (0.13.3), greelet (2.0.2) dependencies in my poetry project
I need to install some dependencies for a project using poetry, but when I try poetry install transformers==0.13.3 it won't work due to this error :
This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with tokenizers (0.13.3) not supporting PEP 517 builds.

I tried many things :

pip install "transformers==0.13.3" --no-cache-dir to install directly in my venv (.py files still unable to find transformers, even if I found it in the venv...)
installing rust in the venv with the command line provided by rust doc curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh (didn't work due to sh not recognized as command or path...)
pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "tokenizers (==0.13.3)", which is the recommanded solution by the error (didn't work and gave me the same error)


why do you use " " in pip? I should be  tokenizers==0.13.3 ?

did you activate venv before running pip and other commands? You may also try to use python -m pip ... instead of pip but also after activating venv. And probably poetry you have to also run after activating venv.

do you use Windows, Linux or MacOS? Linux has sh, MacOS probably also should have sh, but Windows don't have it. You may redirect curl to file curl ... > file.txt and probably you get bat which you may try to run directly like any other file .bat

This page: https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started should give you the correct installation file for your platform (on Windows, that's rustup-init.exe, either 32 bits or 64 bits).
